# Python-IGraph Attributes

Tags: python, igraph

I am looking into converting some code from Python NetworkX to Python-IGraph. When adding nodes and edges to a graph, NetworkX very easily allows you to do:
`g.add_node(a[0], n=a[1])` where a[0] is the node label and a[1] is the value of the attribute "n". How can we add attributes to a node and similarly to an edge, when creating them with Python-IGraph? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! What you're looking for is here ([edges](https://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.Graph-class.html#add_edge) and [vertices](https://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.Graph-class.html#add_vertex)).  Here's the overview:

To add an edge or vertex with an attribute:

`g.add_edge(source, target, some_attribute=some_value)`

`g.add_vertex(name, some_attribute=some_value)`

Comment: What if we wanted to add multiple edges with attributes? This doesn't work: ```g.add_edges([(0,1,n=2),(0,2,n=1),(1,3,n=3),(2,3,n=5),(5,4,n=2),(5,6,n=3),(6,4,n=1)])```